# How to group array by object property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm have array duplicate data.
I need group array Come together

```
const data = [
    { id: 1, name: "john", cardId: "0001" }, 
    { id: 1, name: "john", cardId: "0001" }, 
    { id: 1, name: "john", cardId: "0002" }, 
    { id: 2, name: "poul", cardId: "0003" },
    { id: 2, name: "poul", cardId: "0003" },
    { id: 2, name: "poul", cardId: "0004" }
];
```

I need group duplicate data. Come together And have only one
like this >>

```
const res = [ 
    { id: 1, name: "john", card: [{ cardId: "0001" }, { cardId: "0002"} ] },
    { id: 2, name: "poul", card: [{ cardId: "0003" }, { cardId: "0004"} ] } 
];
```

Thank You Very Much for help.

Comment: Is the data always sorted by id/name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = [
 { id: 1, name: "john", cardId: "0001" }, 
 { id: 1, name: "john", cardId: "0001" }, 
 { id: 1, name: "john", cardId: "0002" }, 
 { id: 2, name: "poul", cardId: "0003" },
 { id: 2, name: "poul", cardId: "0003" },
 { id: 2, name: "poul", cardId: "0004" }
];

var res = [];
data.forEach(a => {
 var searchResultInRes = res.find(x => x.id == a.id);
 if (searchResultInRes) {
  if (!searchResultInRes.card.some(x => x.cardId == a.cardId)) {
   searchResultInRes.card.push({ cardId: a.cardId });
  }
 } else {
  res.push({ id: a.id, name: a.name, card: [{ cardId: a.cardId }] });
 }
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group the items based on `name`. Create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) property called `card` to get unique `cardId`s for each `name`. Then loop through the set to create the output

```js
const data = [
    { id: 1, name: "john", cardId: "0001" }, 
    { id: 1, name: "john", cardId: "0001" }, 
    { id: 1, name: "john", cardId: "0002" }, 
    { id: 2, name: "poul", cardId: "0003" },
    { id: 2, name: "poul", cardId: "0003" },
    { id: 2, name: "poul", cardId: "0004" }
];

const merged = data.reduce((r, { id, name, cardId }) => {
  r[name] = r[name] || { id, name, card: new Set };
  r[name].card.add(cardId)
  return r;
}, {})

const output = Object.values(merged).map(({ card, id, name }) => 
        ({ id, name, card: [...card].map(cardID => ({ cardID })) }) )
      
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data =
    [{id: 1, name: 'john', cardId: '0001'}, {id: 1, name: 'john', cardId: '0001'},
      {id: 1, name: 'john', cardId: '0002'}, {id: 2, name: 'poul', cardId: '0003'},
      {id: 2, name: 'poul', cardId: '0003'}, {id: 2, name: 'poul', cardId: '0004'}];

let grouped = data.reduce((acc, {id, name, cardId}) => {
  let d = acc.find(d => d.id === id);
  if (!d)
    acc.push({id, name, card: [cardId]});
  else if (!d.card.includes(cardId))
    d.card.push(cardId);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(grouped);
```